# Calculate $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\frac{2}{1 + e^x} - 1 + \frac{x}{2}}{x^3}$ using Taylor polynomial

Tags: calculus, limits, taylor-expansion

For an assignment on Taylor expansion we are given the following limit to determine:

$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\frac{2}{1 + e^x} - 1 + \frac{x}{2}}{x^3}$

From a previous subproblem of the assignment I have already expressed a Taylor polynomial of the third degree as:

$p_3(x) = 1 - \frac{1}{2} x + \frac{1}{24} x^3$

My solution is, therefore, to write the expression with the additional term $\mathcal{O}(x^4)$ so that:

$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\frac{2}{1 + e^x} - 1 + \frac{x}{2}}{x^3} = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1 - \frac{1}{2} x + \frac{1}{24} x^3 + \mathcal{O}(x^4) - 1 + \frac{x}{2}}{x^3} = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\frac{1}{24} x^3 + \mathcal{O}(x^4)}{x^3} = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1}{24} \mathcal{O}(x) = \frac{1}{24}$

Any additional terms in the expansion will contain $x$ and thus approach zero and not contribute to the value of the limit.

A couple of questions:

1. Does this look like a valid solution to the problem?
2. What are some conceptual ways to look at this, if I want to fully understand why I can substitute an exact expression with an approximation? To me it still doesn't sit right that this is allowed.

Comment: You are not using an approximation. The big O notation encapsulates the actual error and it tends to $0$ in the limit.

Comment: Your solution is correct. Nice work!

Comment: @PeterForeman Thank you for the comment, this makes sense once I thought about it some more. And can I say, what a cool method this is!